# What is the difference between limitedParallelism vs a fixed thread pool dispatcher?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, parallel-processing, threadpool, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to use Kotlin coroutines to perform multiple HTTP calls concurrently, rather than one at a time, but I would like to avoid making *all* of the calls concurrently, to avoid rate limiting by the external API.

If I simply launch a coroutine for each request, they all are sent near instantly. So I looked into the [limitedParallelism](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-dispatcher/limited-parallelism.html) function, which sounds very close to what I need, and some [stack overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71723785) suggest is the recommended solution. Older [answers to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50868979) suggested using [newFixedThreadPoolContext](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/new-fixed-thread-pool-context.html).

The documentation for that function mentioned `limitedParallelism` as a preferred alternative "if you do not need a separate thread pool":

> If you do not need a separate thread-pool, but only have to limit effective parallelism of the dispatcher, it is recommended to use CoroutineDispatcher.limitedParallelism instead.

However, when I write my code to use `limitedParallelism`, it does not reduce the number of concurrent calls, compared to `newFixedThreadPoolContext` which does.

In the example below, I replace my network calls with `Thread.sleep`, which does not change the behavior.

```kotlin
// method 1
val fixedThreadPoolContext = newFixedThreadPoolContext(2)

// method 2
val limitedParallelismContext = Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(2)

runBlocking {
  val jobs = (1..1000).map {
    // swap out the dispatcher here
    launch(limitedParallelismContext) {
      println("started $it")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      println("    finished $it")
    }
  }
  jobs.joinAll()
}
```

The behavior for `fixedThreadPoolContext` is as expected, no more than 2 of the coroutines runs at a time, and the total time to finish is several minutes (1000 times one second each, divided by two at a time, roughly 500 seconds).

However, for `limitedParallelismContext`, all "started #" lines print immediately, and one second later, all "finished #" lines print and the program completes in just over 1 total second.

**Why does `limitedParallelism` not have the same effect as using a separate thread pool? What *does* it accomplish?**

Comment: works as expected for me, what version of corutines are you using?

Comment: I am using kotlinx-coroutines-core 1.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code slightly so that every coroutine takes 200ms to complete and it prints the time when it is completed. Then I pasted it to [play.kotlinlang.org](https://play.kotlinlang.org) to check:

```kotlin
/**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code.
 * play.kotlinlang.org
 */
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    // method 1
    val fixedThreadPoolContext = newFixedThreadPoolContext(2, "Pool")

    // method 2
    val limitedParallelismContext = Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(2)

    runBlocking {
      val jobs = (1..10).map {
        // swap out the dispatcher here
        launch(limitedParallelismContext) {
          println("it at ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
          Thread.sleep(200)
        }
      }
      jobs.joinAll()
    }
}
```

And there using kotlin 1.6.21 the result is as expected:

```
it at 1652887163155
it at 1652887163157
it at 1652887163358
it at 1652887163358
it at 1652887163559
it at 1652887163559
it at 1652887163759
it at 1652887163759
it at 1652887163959
it at 1652887163959
```

Only 2 coroutines are executed at a time.

Comment: Thank you for confirming the behavior and the play.kotlinlang.org link. It seems I had some other issue with by workspace, and when I run your code (or the snippet from my original question) the behavior is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this keeping the loop synchronous and batching the calls. [Example playground](https://pl.kotl.in/hKvoqjT6x):

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        fun t(): Long = System.currentTimeMillis() - start

        (1..50).chunked(2).forEach { ids ->
            println("launching $ids at ${t()}")
            ids.map {
                launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    delay(100)
                    println("finished $it at ${t()}")
                }
            }.joinAll()
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
launching [1, 2] at 24
finished 2 at 161
finished 1 at 161
launching [3, 4] at 163
finished 3 at 264
finished 4 at 264
launching [5, 6] at 264
finished 5 at 365
finished 6 at 365
launching [7, 8] at 365
finished 7 at 465
finished 8 at 465
launching [9, 10] at 466
finished 9 at 566
finished 10 at 566
```